# How to download file in google chrome extension without opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, browser-tab

I'm currently developing a Google Chrome extension and I need to be able to initiate a file download from the popup. The idea is that the user clicks a link and the download starts. I can do this by creating a new tab and setting the url to the download link, but I would like to avoid opening a new tab, or at least opening it and closing it as soon as the download begins.

Is it possible to do what I want? How? Is it possible to do it programmatically, from the event page?

Thanks for any help.